# Integrating over the region between a line tangent to a circle, and the circle itself

Tags: integration, geometry

[image]

If I want to integrate a function between $x=$ $0$ to $R$ (the cricle radius) and $y = 0$ to the lower half of the circle how do I describe the upper limit on the dy integral (see picture)?

The function I need to integrate over this region is $e^{-b(x^{2}+y^{2})}$. If you can integrate this over the region that would be great, but describing the upper limit as a function of $x$ would do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = R - \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$. That's because the circle equation is $(y-R)^2 + x^2 = R^2$.

The choice of the negative square root is because you want the lower rather than the upper limb of the circle.

Comment: Ok so you can deal with the circle equation. Cheers!